# Go SQLX sqlx.DB Get("sql_function") does not return any value

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx

This is my function:

```
func (a *AirlinesRepository) Get(id int) *models.Airline {
   airline := models.Airline{}

   a.DB.Get(&airline, "SELECT * FROM fn_airlines_getby_id(?)", id)

   return &airline
}
```

After executing DB.Get, airline has all the properties set with zero value instead of being populated with the sql function result. **I Also tried with "SELECT fn_airlines_getby_id(?)" and "fn_airlines_getby_id(?)"**

Airline has the properties:

```
type Airline struct {
  Id   int64  `db:"id"`
  Name string `db:"name"`
}
```

And the function is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_airlines_getby_id(p_id INT)
RETURNS TABLE (id INT, name VARCHAR) AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT a.id AS id, a.name AS name FROM airlines as a WHERE a.id = p_id;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**UPDATE**:
Looking at the Postgres's logs I found the next:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")" at character 30
STATEMENT:  SELECT fn_airlines_getby_id(?)
```

So seems that `sqlx` is not parsing the value that should go instead of `?` (It works well with normal queries)

This is a Postgres database and the function exists.

Comment: What does the error say? You know that `?` is not a postgres thing, right? Does `sqlx` fix that for you automatically? If not you should not use it, you should instead use the proper postgres specific parameter placeholder.

Comment: Hi @mkopriva, `sqlx` is supposed to populate `?` with the value given as parameter. It works well for common queries but as you mentioned, after looking at the logs, seems that this is the problem, the `?` is not being populated with the proper value.

Comment: So have you tried it with postgresql specific parameter placeholder, i.e. `$1`? If so, what was the result?

Comment: @mkopriva worked using `SELECT * FROM fn($1)`! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Postgres's parameter placeholder instead of sqlx one.
Change from

```
SELECT fn_airlines_getby_id(?)
```

To:

```
SELECT * FROM fn_airlines_getby_id($1)
```